# Azure Spring Apps deployment with Maven causes error : Invalid arguments: DeploymentSettings must be provided

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, maven, azure-spring-cloud

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot application to Microsoft Azure Spring Apps using Maven.

I strictly followed this tutorial from Microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/how-to-maven-deploy-apps , except for the azure-spring-apps-maven-plugin which had to be upgraded from 1.10.0 to 1.17.0, as per follows :

`mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-apps-maven-plugin:1.17.0:config`

But when running the deploy command with the sample project :

`mvn azure-spring-apps:deploy`

The following *"Invalid arguments: DeploymentSettings must be provided"* error occurs :

```
[ERROR] Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$StaticThrowable: Operator has been terminated
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.680 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-02T19:06:23+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-apps-maven-plugin:1.17.0:deploy (default-cli) on project hellospring: create or update Spring app(hellospring) from config: AzureToolkitRuntimeException: create Azure Spring App deployment (default): Status code 400, "{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Invalid arguments: DeploymentSettings must be provided.","details":[{"code":"BadArgument","message":"DeploymentSettings must be provided.","target":"Properties.DeploymentSettings"}]}}" -> [Help 1]
```

The HelloSpring sample application does not require any specific configuration (no database, no file storage, no https certificates, etc.).

Any idea of what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same issue. Have you found the workaround or solution?

Comment: Not yet. I had some unsuccessful contacts with Azure support, I hope they'll get back to me.

Comment: I visit this issue which were informed fixed in 1.17.0. According to the discussion, the issue was narrowed down to action of deploying to the Azure Spring Apps Consumption Plan. That was my case as well.
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/issues/2268
With 1.17.0 released, it fixed this error but I haven't seen any report of whether the deployment to Azure Spring Apps Consumption Plan would success since they also stated that they doesn't have plan to support the plan soon.
What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Spring Apps deployment with Maven causes error : Invalid arguments: DeploymentSettings must be provided

I would suggest you to run `mvn clean install` before deploying your application to Azure Spring Apps.

And also Check if the below configuration is being added in your pom.xml file after running `mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-apps-maven-plugin:1.17.0:config`.

```xml
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-spring-apps-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.0</version>
        <configuration>
                    
            <subscriptionId>Azure_SUbscription_id</subscriptionId>
            <resourceGroup>Resource_group_name</resourceGroup>
            <clusterName>kpspringapp</clusterName>
            <appName>springboot-crud</appName>
            <isPublic>false</isPublic>
            <deployment>
                  <cpu>1</cpu>
                  <memoryInGB>1</memoryInGB>
                  <instanceCount>1</instanceCount>
                  <runtimeVersion>Java 11</runtimeVersion>
                  <resources>
                      <resource>
                          <filtering/>
                          <mergeId/>
                          <targetPath/>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                          <includes>
                               <include>*.jar</include>
                          </includes>
                       </resource>
                   </resources>
              </deployment>
         </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

---

I have created a spring boot application and deployed to Azure Spring Apps:

1. Logged into Azure via command line.

[image]

2. Generating the configurations to deploy the Spring Boot application to Azure Spring Apps by running `mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-apps-maven-plugin:1.17.0:config` command.
   This will ask to select the *subscription, Resource group, Azure Spring Apps name, Java runtime version* etc., and then generate the configurations required for deployment.

[image]
[image]

I was also getting errors initially and couldn't deploy the application.
But, after running the command  `mvn clean install`, I was able to deploy the application to spring apps.

[image]
[image]
[image]

***Deploying the application to Azure Spring Apps:***

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Response:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. However, the "mvn clean install" didn't change anything. My Azure account has access to two subscriptions, I wonder if this may be related.

Comment: Even if you have multiple subscriptions, you will get options to select your preferred subscription when you run the command `mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-apps-maven-plugin:1.17.0:config` as I shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Everything works perfectly if you are NOT using the "Standard Consumption" plan. If you use at least "Basic" everything works as it should. I have retested this a few times and each time it works fine with "Basic" but not "Consumption" as I get same error as you each time.

Obviously this is not ideal, perhaps there is update coming soon? I would much rather use the new consumption plan

Comment: Thanks for the test and confirmation Dan. Obviously the new plan is my preference as well.

Comment: I am going to keep testing will definitely let you know if I find anything si